# How to get the difference between the frequency of two fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a PostgreSQL database table that contains two columns `a` and `b`.
When I query all the entries of the table I get:

```
{1, 2},
{2, 3},
{2, 3}
```

So the value:

- (1) appeared in field `a` 1 time  and in field `b` 0 times
- (2) appeared in field `a` 2 times and in field `b` 1 time
- (3) appeared in field `a` 0 times and in field `b` 2 times

I want to get the following output:

```
{1, 1},
{2, 1},
{3, -2}
```

where the first field is the value stored in the database and the second field is difference.

How can I achieve that?

I first query the database and the result is in `query_result`
then I get the frequency of the first and second element:

```
f0 = query_result |> Enum.frequencies_by(&elem(&1, 0))
f1 = query_result |> Enum.frequencies_by(&elem(&1, 1))
(f0 |> Map.keys) ++ (f1 |> Map.keys) |> Enum.uniq |> Enum.into(%{}, fn key -> {key, (f0[key] || 0) - (f1[key] || 0)} end)
```

I am looking for a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single query:

```sql
SELECT val, COALESCE(a.ct, 0) - COALESCE(b.ct, 0) AS freq_diff
FROM  (
   SELECT a AS val, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT b AS val, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) b USING (val);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6JQpVLjR)

[`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.2), because either value may be missing in the other column.

[`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to defend against NULL values resulting from the join.